# How to auto generate date(Week End) and 0 values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I currently have a graphs that displays totals hours worked per date based on the below SQL.

```
select sum(hours)/40 from resource where project IN ('Admin', 'Absence','Enhancements') group by date;
```

The table looks like this.

[image: table]

This all works fine and graph displays as long as there is an entry for every value for each date. Otherwise the it misses dates and the data is displayed out of sync.

I was thinking that one solution would be have some SQL that generated 0 values for a Temp person (AdminUser) for all fields each week, which would stop this, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution as my SQL is fairly basic. Or should I add a column for each field instead of the below?

Whats the best solution here? And the sql to implement it?

DN: SQLITE

Structure:

[image: strcuture]

Unique Index - To update the value instead of adding a new one when Date, Name and Project match

[image: unique index]

Note: The below SQL is used to generate X Axis for graph - Dates:

```
select distinct(date) from resource;
```

This is what the graph looks like, if it helps.

[image: graph]

Comment: "hours" is varchar(16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a CASE statement based on my understanding of your requirements as follows:

```
 select 
case when sum(hours) > 0 Then
    CAST(CAST(SUM(hours) as DECIMAL(5,2))/40 AS Decimal(5,2))
else 0 end as [hours],
[DATE]
from resource group by date
```

This is saying that if hours is greater than zero then use your formula, else return 0.  It is worth checking what your setting for ANSI NULLS is first.  Resource.Hours must be an integer.

Comment: I have made a change to the SQL.  Please take a look.

Comment: The problem is that some dates don't exist in the db, right? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Almost, Some dates won't appear for some fields or for no fields. For example. Admin may have hours for 03/03/2013. But Enhancments may not for that date, but may have 40 hours for the 10/03/2013 which could cause the data to be out of sync as it is ordering by date and enhancements doesn't have any entry for that date. Or would sql align values with the appropriate date?

Comment: Are you saying that for 01/10/2013 you would expect three records returned all with hours=0?

Answer (score 1):

I think a calendar table will help you a lot.

```
pragma foreign_keys = on;

create table calendar (
  calendar_date date primary key
);

insert into calendar values ('2013-02-01');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-02');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-03');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-04');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-05');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-06');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-07');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-08');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-09');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-10');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-11');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-12');
insert into calendar values ('2013-02-13');
```

Also, a table of projects.

```
create table projects (
  project_name varchar(16) primary key
);

insert into projects values ('Admin');
insert into projects values ('Absence');
insert into projects values ('Enhancements');
```

Because SQLite is stingy in its implementation of outer joins, use a view to make this easier.

```
create view project_dates as 
select c.calendar_date, p.project_name 
from calendar c, projects p;
```

Now you can select from that view, and use a left join to preserve those rows as you bring in data from the table "resource". I inserted some columns so you can see what's going on.

```
select p.calendar_date, p.project_name, 
       ifnull(sum(r.hours), 0) total_hrs, 
       ifnull(sum(r.hours)/40, 0) divided_hrs
from project_dates p
left join resource r
       on r.date = p.calendar_date
      and r.project = p.project_name
where p.calendar_date between '2013-02-03' and '2013-02-10'
group by p.calendar_date, p.project_name
order by p.calendar_date, p.project_name;

calendar_date    project_name    total_hrs divided_hrs
--
2013-02-03       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-03       Admin           80        2          
2013-02-03       Enhancements    40        1          
2013-02-04       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-04       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-04       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-05       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-05       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-05       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-06       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-06       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-06       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-07       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-07       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-07       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-08       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-08       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-08       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-09       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-09       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-09       Enhancements    0         0          
2013-02-10       Absence         0         0          
2013-02-10       Admin           0         0          
2013-02-10       Enhancements    30        0
```